# Creating new workspace from TFS commandline - root working dir always added?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

If I run `tf workspace /new /noprompt` to create a local TFS workspace, it appears to automatically create a working folder mapping of $/ -> `current-dir`. This is annoying as I have to remove it before setting up the working folders I actually want. It also means `tf workspace` will fail if another workspace has a working folder to any any sub-dir of my current directory.

e.g. if D: is my TFS dir, running `D:\>tf workspace /new /noprompt ...` will fail if *any* other working folder is set up, because the automatic mapping /$ -> d:\ conflicts.

Isn't it possible to create the workspace with *no* initial working folders? Otherwise I deliberately have to change-dir to some 'fake' directory to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use existing workspace as a template: [`tf workspace /new /template:<wokspacename>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se)

Alternatively use the [`tf workfold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6) command.

Comment: you can't use `tf workfold` until after creating the workspace with the automatic root mapping, which is the whole problem. Is using a template the only way to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, template is the only way

Comment: Is there a way to specify the root drive and directory when using the /template switch? The template might be on C: but what if I need it on D:?

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution to this problem. `tf workspace /new` command automatically creates mapping between `$/` and current directory. Thus, you need to do these steps:

1. Change your current folder
2. Run `tf workspace /new` command. It creates unneeded `$/` mapping
3. Run `tf workfold /map` command which maps necessary TFS folder into current folder. It overrides unnecessary `$/` with the value you provide.